# How to maintain text padding on EditText when there are multiple lines

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

For an application that I'm working on, I have an editText that I allow users to input data into. I have defined padding on the input that is not maintained when multiple lines of text are entered in. For example:

[image]

After adding a second line of text:

[image]

As more and more lines are added, I'm also seeing that the position of the edittext in the parent view gets lower and lower:

[image]

My XML for the editText is as follows:

```
  <EditText
            android:id="@+id/message_edit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.75"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/someBackground"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp_12"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/dp_3"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:hint="Type here"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/dp_4"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp_17" />
```

I assume that both issues are related given but i'm not sure what the underlying cause is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead `android:paddingLeft` and `android:paddingRight` use only `android:padding` to add `padding` on all side. Check below:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/message_edit"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.75"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_8"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/someBackground"
    android:padding="@dimen/dp_12"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:hint="Type here"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/dp_4"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sp_17" />
```

**Result:**

[image]